# jQuery animated menu#hover function()

Tags: jquery

I have a horizontal menu, which is animated by JQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/BTD2F/5/

The problem(s):
I a have a 'current' parent item, its ul shall be shown. If I hover another parent item, the ul which is currently shown, shall be hidden. That one form the hoverd item shall be shown and fade out if the hover() is 'finsihed'. All that does not work, like it should. You can see the code on jsfiddler.
Please try to hover 'Moda' and you'll see the problem.

Many Thanks in advance,
Lars

Comment: which browsers do you need this to work in. Specifically, is IE6 support required?

Answer (score 0):

```
       jQuery("#headnav_primary .top-item").hover(

     function(){

        jQuery('.current-menu-item ul').hide('fast');
         jQuery(this).find('ul').show('slow');

        },    
       function() {
        jQuery(this).find('ul').hide('fast');
           });
```

Add class 'top-item' to your header li links.

Comment: @AR I just did and made an update on js fiddler. The problmes are still there. :(

Comment: I've updated the code. Works fine for me.  i really don't see the need to specifically hide .current-menu-item as it's not visible by default, so I would just remove that line altogether.

Comment: @AR Please have alook at this new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdVbd/ and feel free to change it. I changed it in the way, you dexribe it but it does not work.

Comment: You have to add top-item class to all top-level li elements ('Moda', etc.).

Comment: @AR I did. Sorry, forgot it. But: Please hover 'moda' and try the hover the first item of its 'ul'.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browsers you need this to work in, there are a couple of approaches to getting the sub-menus to appear.

You could change the JavaScript jQuery code to the following, which will simply hide all the subMenus when any `<li>` is entered and display the current `<li>`'s sub-menu.

```
var subMenus = $("#headnav_primary li ul");

$("#headnav_primary li").mouseenter(function() {
    subMenus.hide();
    $(this).children('ul').show('slow');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    subMenus.hide('fast');
});
```

Or remove all the JavaScript completely and just add this one simple CSS rule which displays the sub-menu when the parent `<li>` is hovered.

```
#headnav_primary li:hover ul {
    display:block !important;
}
```

**Note:** This will not work in older browsers, especially IE6. Also, I have added `!important` is because you have currently inlined `style="display:none"` on the sub-menus which is taking precedence. If you remove the inline style you could remove the `!important`.

**Edit:** Here is [**a better demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vcnns/2/) that *only* uses CSS. This will not work in IE6 because it only supports `:hover` on *anchor* tags. If you need IE6 support, I can update, but that will use jQuery.

Comment: Please have a look at the fiddle. I made un update, but there are still problems. Pleaser hover 'moda'.

Comment: @Lars OK, so it is the hovering on the sub-menus that you need help with. I know what the problems is and will update my answer soon. Could you please let me know if you need this to work in IE6?